# Correct verification of request

Tags: php, sql

I think I miss something about the verification of my PHP request. I'm actually doing `$result = $req->fetch();` but `result` always return false for some reason.

```
$bdd = new PDO($conStr,$user,$pass);
$req = $bdd->prepare('INSERT INTO users(login, password, dateregister) VALUES(?, ?, NOW())');
$req->execute(array($loginR,$passwordR));

$result = $req->fetch();
```

Comment: **Never** store plain text passwords. Instead use [`password_hash()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php). If you're using a version of PHP prior to 5.5, do **not** use MD5 or SHA1 to hash passwords. Instead you can use [this compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: @AlexHowansky Ok thanks I'll use that ! :)

Comment: `fetch()` requires `SELECT`, not `INSERT`.

Comment: Check the return value of execute function for success/failure message.

Comment: *"Can you explain why my verification of my sql request doesn't work?"* - Well that part needs to be taken out. What you have now isn't a verification method, it's a different operation altogether, being 2 different animals.

Comment: The question's title and the question itself do not reflect the actual problem here, given the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the return value of execute function for success/failure message

```
$res = $req->execute(array($login_fieldR,$password_fieldR));
   if (!$res )
    {
        echo '<p id="popup_text">Problem..</p>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<p id="popup_text">You are registered ! You can logged in now';
    }
```

Comment: and what about their `$result = $req->fetch();`? you left that part out as to why their code failed. Edit: And their question being: *"Can you explain why my verification of my sql request doesn't work?"* - they want to verify here, so it goes deeper than what was posted.

Comment: that works ! thanks :)